# Immediate access of Facebook User Profile info (e.g. name, email etc)

Tags: android, facebook

A question on Android program working with Facebook SDK. From what I've learnt so far, after login to Facebook, it requires a separate async request to get the graph for the user info. e.g.

```
Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() ...
```

Is there a way to have these (i.e. user_profile) obtained IMMEDIATELY upon login success?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a separate request for the user profile after the login. You can not get the user profile IMMEDIATELY after the login without making a separate Graph User information request.

Comment: Thanks BeingMiAkashs. Whatever even the simpler item such as UserID and User Name? Are they inaccessible as well during the initial login?